# Can anyone tell me how to read the sentence here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: The Times
Title: Britain's most haunted cottage
The author went to live in a haunted cottage, where a ghostly figure has been seen by several visitors. One night during his stay there, he finally saw the man. The following is his description.

Unnerved, I lay awake listening to the sound of owls scratching in the roof. And at
4.48am, he appeared: the silent staring man. A freezing flush passed through my entire body,
and - I'm not sure that this is a psychic phenomenon - my testicles tightened. I lay silently
under the duvet, disorientated with exhaustion and anxiety. It wasn't until dawn that I dared
reach for my glasses and a first clear sight of the ghoul. It wasn't my finest hour. ***I had been
terrified by a silver 14in portable TV.***
Before leaving I chatted to Daryll, a local dairy farmer. He hadn't heard about Mellingray's
haunting, but said that “if there's anything, it's probably a farmer who committed suicide. They
get isolated and depressed and end it in the barn with a shotgun or rope”.

I don't know how to read the sentence in bold? Why did he mention a portable TV here?

Comment: It's not very clear, but apparently when he put his spectacles on he realised that the 'ghost' was an image on the TV screen. (Why? Was it a reflection, or had the set somehow been switched on?)

Comment: His sight isn't great. What he mistook for a ghost was a blurry silhouette of the TV in his room at dawn.

Comment: The putting on of his glasses is a great big clue. Also, we say that an occasion 'wasn't our finest hour' when it was something that we feel shame or embarrassment about.

Answer (score 1):

> It wasn't until dawn that I dared reach for my glasses and a first clear sight of the ghoul. It wasn't my finest hour. I had been terrified by a silver 14 in portable TV.

The fact the author needed to reach for his glasses to get his "first **clear sight** of the ghoul" indicates that previously his vision was blurry.  This was producing an optical illusion of a ghoul.  When he put his glasses on, his vision sharpened and he could see what was causing the illusion - a **silver 14 inch portable TV**.  The incomplete picture formed by his blurry eyesight in the dark had turned the TV into a ghost in his mind.